# Value type in C# returning type instead of underlying amount

Tags: c#

I am creating a Volume value type and so far so good but when I overrode the multiplication operator and wrote a unit test, if the test fails instead of getting the expected and actual amounts I get the full qualified type name.

There's not much in the code:

```
private decimal amount;

public Volume(decimal value)
{
   amount = value;
}

public static implicit operator Volume(decimal value)
{
   return new Volume(value);
}

//... continue same methods with all number types

public static Volume operator *(Volume left, decimal right)
{
   return new Volume(left.amount * right);
}
```

With this code if I write a failing test instead of getting the expected and actual amount failing message I get:

> Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected: <MyTypes.Utilities.Volume>. Actual: <MyTypes.Utilities.Volume>.

I tried adding the following:

```
public static implicit operator Decimal(Volume value)
{
    return value.amount;
}
```

Not only this did not work but now the test that proves the type can be initialized with a decimal amount fails with the same message:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VolumeTypeGetsInitializedByDecimalValue()
{
    Decimal value = 123456781.1235657789464356m;

    Volume volume = value;

    Assert.AreEqual(value, volume);
}
```

This is the first time I try to do this so I am not sure why it is behaving this way. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like you provided an implementation of the equals operator

Comment: You should override `ToString` as well. The test framework is calling `ToString` which is the type name by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First way is to replace

```
Assert.AreEqual(value, volume);
```

with:

```
Assert.AreEqual((Volume)value, volume);
```

another way is to replace assert string with:

```
Assert.IsTrue(value.Equals(volume), string.Format("It was expected to get '{0}' but got '{1}'.", volume, value));
```

and override ToString to be like:

```
public override String ToString(){
    return amount.ToString();
}
```

**Update**

To make things "right", additionally to overriding `ToString` method I also do recommend to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods with marking `amount` field as readonly:

```
private readonly decimal amount;

public bool Equals(Volume other)
{
    return amount == other.amount;
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is Volume ? Equals((Volume)obj) : base.Equals(obj);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return amount.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: I checked all the stuff I wrote and it worked.
So in case of downvoting please explain the mistake to let me know where's is the mistake. I like feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

To see the decimal value enclosed by your Volume class when it is printed by your test, just implement an override of `ToString()`:

```
public override String ToString(){
    return amount.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted.  This seems like the right answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but simply overriding ToString() does not work for me. Are we both talking about mstest framework?

Comment: Nope, the above is a solution to this problem when using NUnit.  Maybe you should mention your testing framework in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`Assert.AreEqual` calls `object.Equals`, implimented like this. First it compares 2 objects with object.ReferenceEquals, if they are not equal it checks if one of them null and if not it calls `Equals` method of one of objects.

```
static bool Equals(object a, object b)
{
    if(ReferenceEquals(a, b)
        return true;
    if(a == null || b == null)
        return false;
    return a.Equals(b);
}
```

In c# all value (struct) type inherit from `ValueType`, which overrides `Object` Equals method. First it compares types, in your case it is `Volume` and `decimal`, so `Equals` returns false. For equal types it compares field values via reflection. So if you want `Assert.AreEqual` to compare `Volume` and `decimal`, you'll have to override `Equals` like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is decimal)
    {
        return amount == (decimal) obj;
    }
    if (obj is Volume)
    {
        return amount == ((Volume) obj).amount;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Still it is possible that `Assert.AreEqual(Decimal, Volume)` and `Assert.AreEqual(Volume, Decimal)` will produce different results, so I'd recomend you to test with `Assert.IsTrue(Volume.Equals(Decimal))`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the command `Assert.AreEqual`.  Although I cannot speak directly to how the implementation works ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx)), I believe that the function is using the operator `==`.

In order for your volume to work correctly with `Assert.AreEqual` you will need to define 
the operators `==` and `!=`.

**EDIT**: Found documentation that suggests that `Assert.AreEqual` implements `IEquatable`
See [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/493426/)

Such as

```
public static bool operator !=(Volume valA, Volume valB)
{
    return valA.amount != valB.amount;
}

public static bool operator ==(Volume valA, Volume valB)
{
    return valA.amount == valB.amount;
}
```

**Note**: You will also need to implement Equals & GetHashCode (or use IEquatable)